# D3.js Bar Chart won't append, creates a new chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I have been using d3.js to create a bar chart from a table of results. All the code is below. One table gets the data from the csv file. Then clones it to another table, when this happens I want the bar chart bars to change. But a new bar chart is created instead. Any advice or help would be really appreciated, thanks.

```
updateCode()
function test()
{
var source = document.getElementById('table');
var destination = document.getElementById('myclonediv');
var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
copy.setAttribute('id', 'myclonediv');
destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);
var canvas;
createGraph()
}
function createGraph()
{
    d3.csv(googlesheet, function(data) {


        //create container - canvas
        canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            //width and height
            .attr("width", 300)
            .attr("height", 1000)

        //add bars  - rectangle 
        canvas.selectAll("rect")
            //loading data variable
            .data(data)
            //enter method
            .enter()
                //append rectangle for each element
                .append("rect")
                //width - d will reference data, d.age - from csv file * 10 so bars are bigger
                .attr("width", function(d) { return d.Random * 10})
                //was 50 now 48 to allow space between bars
                .attr("height", 48)
                // y function of the index, for each element
                .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i *50})
                //colour blue
                .attr("fill", "blue");

            //var newData = parsedCSV.replace(',', '');
            //var test = parsedCSV.substring(parsedCSV.indexOf(",") + 1);


            //add text to each bar - repeat before
        canvas.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
                .append("text")
                    //white text
                .attr("fill", "red")
                    //same position on each bar -- + 24 is half of 48 in height -- now middle of bar
                .attr("y", function(d,i) { return i *50+24})
                    //what text - d.name
                .text(function(d) { return d.Random; }) 

            }) 


}
function remove()
{
    var tableCode = d3.select("#table");
tableCode.selectAll("*").remove();
    updateCode()
}


function updateCode()
{
  var tabulate = function (data,columns) {                      
   var table = d3.select('#table').append('table')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody')

    thead.append('tr')
      .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
      .append('th')
        .text(function (d) { return d })

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
      .append('tr')

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
                return { column: column, value: row[column] }
          })
      })
      .enter()
    .append('td')
      .text(function (d) { return d.value })

  return table;
}

d3.csv(googlesheet,function (data) {
    var columns = ['Test','Random']
  tabulate(data,columns)



})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you run the `createGraph()` function, you do this:

```
canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

Which means your "canvas" selection is of a new svg element each time you run the function. With this new svg you select all rectangles and do an enter selection:

```
canvas.selectAll("rect")
    //loading data variable
    .data(data)
    //enter method
    .enter()
```

But, as there are no rectangles in the new svg, the enter selection creates a rectangle for each element. Same for text. And since it's a new svg, you've duplicated your graph.

(*The enter selection will create a DOM element for each item in the data array that has no corresponding DOM element, your selection is empty, so it creates one element for each item in the array.*)

The easiest fix would be to not append the svg in the createGraph function - append it in the html or before the function is called. Then in the createGraph function just select it:

```
svg = d3.select("svg") // assuming you have only one svg, otherwise give it an id or class
```

Now you have to execute a proper enter/update/exit cycle, but it's not clear what version of d3 you are using which is important because are differences between v3 and v4.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do this now it adds onto a bar. So the first time a bar appears and it is 5, when I update and the bar should be 1, it is now 6. I don't want to delete the old bars as I want transition to happen. 
I am using http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js